# putting equation references in parentheses in Lyx

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, lyx

I am trying to typeset a Latex document in LyX. My equation references are showing up as "Eq. 1 blah blah". I would like for them to have parentheses around the numbers, i.e. show up as "Eq. (1) blah blah". Additionally, I would like this to be *only* for equations, i.e. I want to continue having "Fig. 1 blah blah", not "Fig. (1) blah blah".

It seems that there is a [similar question that has been asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192426/putting-all-cross-references-in-brackets-in-lyx), but that person wanted parentheses around *all* references, as clarified by the first comment in the question.

How can I do this for just equations only? Ideally some kind of preamble addition that only parenthesizes the equations while not touching any of the other references (Figs, Tables, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

When you add the cross-reference, set `(<reference>)` as the *Format*:

[image]

For existing cross-references, right click the cross-reference and select the same format:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for following up on this years after the fact, but this approach seems very manual. Sometimes, especially in large documents, it's possible that some references will be missed and end up being formatted differently. Is there a way of making this formatting choice a setting, that automatically gets applied to all equation references?

Comment: @mwalth I don't know.